# ThreadSanitizer says my Atomic Inc/Dec has data races, false positive?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, locking

I wrote my atomic_inc for increment an integer using asm, it is actually used for referencing counting for shared objects. gcc 4.8.2 -fsanitize=thread reports data races and I finally found it was likely cause by my atomic_inc. I don't believe my code has a bug there to do with data races, is that a false positive by tsan?

```
static inline int atomic_add(volatile int *count, int add) {
    __asm__ __volatile__(
            "lock xadd %0, (%1);"
            : "=a"(add)
            : "r"(count), "a"(add)
            : "memory"
    );
    return add;
}

void MyClass::Ref() {
    // std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(s_ref);
    atomic_add(&_refs, 1);
}
void MyClass::Unref() {
    // std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(s_ref);
    int n = atomic_add(&_refs, -1) - 1;
    // lock.unlock();
    assert(n >= 0);
    if (n <= 0) {
        delete this;
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the (so far) 2 good answers below, your asm is also incorrect. This code changes the value of an input-only parameter (count).  If you must use asm, perhaps something like `asm("lock xadd %[add], %[count]" : [add] "+r"(add), [count] "+m"(count) : : "memory", "cc");`?

Answer (score 2):

Part of your problem is that gcc doesn't look inside the asm.

The other part of your problem is that `volatile` doesn't make a variable thread-safe.

Given `__asm__` means you are committed to gcc, why not use the gcc intrinsics? (They are documented and well tested, and gcc will understand their semantics.)

As to whether the warning is a false positive, I don't know.  The safe thing to do is to assume the problem is genuine.  It is *really* hard to see problems in multi-threaded code (even when you *know* they are there).  (Once we ripped out a very clever piece of code using a published mutex algorithm that was failing and replaced it with a simple spin-lock.  That fixed the failures, but we never could find *why* it failed.)

Comment: I know  there are other atomic functions provided by c++11 or so, but my question is why tsan complains about my code and is that a false complain?

Comment: @bugsking, did you read the answer? It is extremely clear! This is happening because TSAN doesn't know what your ASM is doing, it works on C++ code level. And yes, you should be using gcc intrinsics for atomics (they are **not** C++11 thread thing).

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, the tool cannot see inside your asm. But you shouldn't do that anyway. 
Just use std::atomic and be done with it - that's both thread safe and portable and the compiler knows how to optimize it - unlike your current code.